# How do I parse a concatinated date and time in R?

Tags: r, date, parsing, datetime

The date July, 1, 2016 1:15pm and 43 seconds is given to me as the string 160701131543.

I have an entire column in my data frame of this date time. How should I go about parsing this column into usable data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `as.POSIXct` function and specify the format, in your case the format is year, month, day, hour, minute, second. Read more about formatting date and time data on the `?strptime` help page.

```
as.POSIXct("160701131543", format = "%y%m%d%H%M%S")
[1] "2016-07-01 13:15:43 EDT"
```

The timezone can be changed with the 'tz' parameter.

Comment: Official documentation is preferable: `help(strptime")`

Comment: I tried to apply this to a column with
`ccr$A <- as.POSIXct(ccr$A, format = "%y%m%d%H%M%S")`

And received 'origin must be supplied'

I then put in 
`origin = as.POSIXct("1970-01-01 00:00:00", format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")`

Which still gave the same error

Comment: @KhiemHa You should have provided a reproducible example that illustrated your problem. The code I provided runs without error and answers the question you asked.

Comment: Apologies I found the error, my test file was overwritten by a coworker who was working in excel. The values in the first column ended up saving as 1.6E+9 instead of the full value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option with `lubridate`.  The default `tz` is "UTC".  It can be changed by specifying `tz`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms("160701131543")
#[1] "2016-07-01 13:15:43 UTC"
```